# Cascading Select Boxes in Admin

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, django-admin

I have the following code to implement a cascading select boxes (as the field contract_mod is OneToOneField I can't use django-smart-selects or django-ajax-select).

When I'm creating a fieldset with the fields that I want to be shown, I have to put the contracts_from_selected in order to see the results in the admin interface (since contract_mod remain disabled after applying the code.).

```
fieldsets = [ 
[ None, 
    {
         "fields" : [ 
            ("contracts_from_selected") 
        ]
    } 
]
```

So I guess I should copy to another field the value of contracts_from_selected in order to be used in the fieldset.

Any suggestion?

**models**

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
    def get_name(self):
        return self.name

class Contract(models.Model):
    person        = models.ForeignKey(Person) #person hired
    contract_mod  = models.OneToOneField('self', blank = True, null = True)
    contract_name = models.CharField(max_length=20) #just for testing

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.get_name() + " " +self.contract_name
    def get_name(self):
        return self.person.get_name() #to make sure you get the person name in the admin
    def contract_mod_name(self):
        if self.contract_mod:
            return self.contract_mod.contract_name
        else:
            return ""
```

**admin**

```
class SelectField(forms.ChoiceField):
    def clean(self, value):
        return value

class ContractForm(forms.ModelForm):
    contracts_from_selected = SelectField()
    class Meta:
        model = Contract
        widgets = { 'contract_mod' : forms.widgets.Select(attrs={'hidden' : 'true'}) }

class ContractAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = CForm
    list_display = ('contract_name','get_name','contract_mod_name')#what you like
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        if request.POST.get('contracts_from_selected'):
            obj.contract_mod=Contract.objects.get(id=int(request.POST.get('contracts_from_selected')))

        obj.save()
```

**change_form**

```
$(function () {
    $("#id_person").change(function () {    
        var options = $("#id_contract_mod option").filter(function () {
            return $(this).html().split(" ")[0] === $("#id_person   option:selected").html();
        }).clone();
        $("#id_contracts_from_selected").empty();
        $("#id_contracts_from_selected").append(options);
    });
});
```

Comment: Why can't you use `django-smart-selects`?

Comment: @dan-klasson Because contract_mod is a OneToOneField with a relationship with itself.

Comment: Yes I read that. Specifically why is that I mean. What's the error?

Comment: `from smart_selects.db_fields import ChainedForeignKey

class Contract(models.Model):
person        = models.ForeignKey(Person)
mod_contratos   = ChainedForeignKey(
        Contract
        chained_field="person",
        chained_model_field="person",
        show_all=False,
        auto_choose=True
        )` And I get [this](http://pastebin.com/aVHxebgT) error.

Comment: Did you import Contract? Seems you're getting an unrelated error.

Comment: @dan-klasson I'm using these fields inside the Contract class so I don't need to import it. I think the problem is because the X field relates to himself. Besides, I'm forced to use a ForeignKey when what I need is a OneToOneField (which is not supported in django-smart-selects).

Comment: I was thinking about copy the values of contracts from selected in any field in order to show it in a fieldset but I don't know how to go about that.